# Lua Loops to Create Multiple Spaced Out Items

Tags: loops, lua, logic, cad

I'm new to Lua. I'm trying to create a plugin in Lua that will create multiple blocks that are spaced out. At the moment I can't seem to get the table function to update the new location of the blocks.

There is a coordinate system and the documentation can be found here
https://github.com/daniel-flassig/pytha-lua-api/wiki/pytha.create_block

The user interface allows the user to enter the number of duplicate blocks they want.

```
for x_panels = 1, data.x_panels do
       
       local position =  {data.origin[1],data.origin[2],data.origin[3]}
       

       local new_stock = pytha.create_block(data.width, data.height, data.thickness, {data.position}) 
             pytha.set_element_name(new_stock, "Stock")
             table.insert(data.cur_elements, new_stock)
             data.x_panels = -1
             table.insert(position,{data.origin[1] + data.width, data.origin[2], data.origin[3]})
        
   end
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Try providing a `step` argument to the lua table and use it to jump every `x` amount until it reaches the condition, the documentation for it is available [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your code, you're using `table.insert()` to attempt to update the position of your next block. What this method is doing is inserting your newly desired position into your already existent position table resulting in:

```
position = {
  data.origin[1], 
  data.origin[2], 
  data.origin[3],
  { data.origin[1] + data.width, data.origin[2], data.origin[3] }
}
```

Additionally, the position variable does not seem to be used in your create block, and from the looks of the API you posted, data.position is not available.

My suggestion would be, create your original position table outside of your loop, and update it within your loop by directly setting the values in that table to your newly desired position for the next iteration:

```
-- assuming format of data.origin = { 0, 0, 0 }
local position = data.origin

for i = 1, data.x_panels do
  pytha.create_block(data.width, data.height, data.thickness, position) 
  pytha.set_element_name(new_stock, "Stock")
  table.insert(data.cur_elements, new_stock)
  position[1] = position[1] + data.width
end
```

You could also use a while loop, since `i` is not actually used, but that's up to you!

Comment: Thank you both. Let me. Try that out and update you.